# How to set the initial value for relationship fields in Django's admin?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-admin, relationship

### Summary

We would like to set the initial selection of the select-boxes representing different kinds of model relationships on a basic "add" or "change" page in the Django admin.
The initial selection should be saved to the database, if the user clicks one of the "Save" buttons.

We specifically want to do this by setting the `initial` value on the form fields (for `ModelAdmin` or `TabularInline`).

The question is:

*What is the proper "value" to assign to* `Field.initial`, *for different kinds of relationship form-fields?*

### Background

Suppose we have a simple `Model` with *one or more* [relationship fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related), i.e. `OneToOneField`, `ForeignKey`, or `ManyToManyField`. By default, the latter has an *implicit* `through` model, but it may also use an *explicit* `through` model, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). An explicit `through` model is a model with [at least](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) two `ForeignKey` fields.

The relationship fields, represented by select-boxes, appear automatically on the standard `ModelAdmin` "add" or "change" forms, except for the `ManyToManyField` with *explicit* `through` model. That one requires an inline, such as the `TabularInline`, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models) in the docs.

Note that the *implicit* `ManyToManyField` is associated with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` on the (admin) form, and the other relationship fields are associated with a `ModelChoiceField`. The latter includes the `ManyToManyField` with *explicit* `through` model, because that is actually represented by a `ForeignKey` field in the `TabularInline`.

### Goal

Now consider a basic Django `ModelAdmin` "add" (or "change") page for this model, including inlines for any *explicit* `through` models. An example based on Django's Pizza-Topping is depicted below.

We want to achieve two goals:

1. set the *initial selection* for one or more of the relationship fields
2. the initial selection must be *saved* to the database if we click one of the "Save" buttons (assuming we did not change the selection manually)

Note that the second one seems trivial, but apparently isn't (see below).

[image: django pizza admin example]

### Approach

As far as I know, there are several ways to achieve this:

- set the model field `default` value, e.g. `ForeignKey.default`, optionally passing a callable ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#default))
- set the `Form.initial` value for the admin form ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial))
- set the `Field.initial` value for the admin form-field ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#initial))

*Regardless* of which approach is "best" for a certain use case, *this question* is about the last approach: setting the value of `Field.initial`.

We do this by extending `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_dbfield` (or `TabularInline.formfield_for_dbfield`), as follows:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'some_relationship_field_name':
        kwargs['initial'] = value
    return super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

The `value` in this example could be an `obj.id`, `obj`, `[obj.id, ...]`, or `[obj, ...]`, where `obj` is a `Model` instance.

### Problem

Depending on the type of relationship field, different types of `value` may or may not work.

For the `ManyToManyField` with implicit `through` model, we can only assign a list of objects, so that one is easy.

For the other relationships, in some cases the initial select-box selection matches the assigned value, but is not saved (e.g. because [Field.has_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/fields/#Field.has_changed) returns `False`). 
In other cases the initial select-box value is saved, but does not match the assigned value.

### Question

So, the obvious question is:

**What is the proper `value` to assign to `Field.initial`, for different kinds of relationship fields on an admin form?**

### Related

Despite having spent quite a lot of time searching, I could not find a clear answer in the documentation, nor on SO, nor anywhere else. Also tried to figure this out through the source code, but that turns out to be quite tricky.

Some similar questions:

- [Django, set initial data to formset with ManyToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5223048)
- [How to set initial data for Django admin model add instance form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10000950)
- [Django AdminForm field default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6164773)
- [django-admin formfield_for_* change default value per/depending on instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2960232)
- [Django - ForeignKey field initial value definition in Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12656529)

Answer (score 1):

The table below shows the results of some experimentation with a dedicated minimal example, using Django 2.1. Based on the table, it appears that:

- `obj` or `obj.id` only work for `OneToOneField` and `ForeignKey`
- `[obj.id]` works for all relationships represented by a `ModelChoiceField`
- `[obj]` only works for the implicit `ManyToManyField`, which is represented by a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`

However, I cannot say what is the *intended* way to do it for each case. For example, it does not make much sense to assign a list for a `ForeignKey` field. However, the funny thing is, that, even though the `ManyToManyField` with explicit `through` model has an inline with a `ModelChoiceField` for a `ForeignKey`, we cannot just assign `obj` or `obj.id`: it must be in a list.

Any comments are much appreciated here.

Key for table 1:

- **1**: select-box initial selection corresponds with value of `Field.initial`
- **2**: select-box initial selection is saved, after clicking "Save" (NOTE: if 1 fails, then the select-box initial selection is the first available option)
- **T**: `TypeError` (object is not iterable)
- **A**: `AttributeError` ('int' object has no attribute 'pk')

Note that our *desired behavior* is **1 & 2**.

Table 1: result of assigning different values to `Field.initial` for different relationship fields

```
|                                                       |  value assigned to Field.initial  |
|-----------------|----------|--------------------------|-------|--------|-------|----------|
| model field     | through  | associated form field    | obj   | obj.id | [obj] | [obj.id] |
|-----------------|----------|--------------------------|-------|--------|-------|----------|
| OneToOneField   | n/a      | ModelChoiceField         | 1 & 2 | 1 & 2  | 2     | 1 & 2    |
| ForeignKey      | n/a      | ModelChoiceField         | 1 & 2 | 1 & 2  | 2     | 1 & 2    |
| ManyToManyField | explicit | ModelChoiceField         | 1     | 1      | 2     | 1 & 2    |
| ManyToManyField | implicit | ModelMultipleChoiceField | T     | T      | 1 & 2 | A        |
```